# Make VBA Fill the TextPage and Click the "Send" Button. WebTelegram

Tags: vba, excel, parsing, telegram

I am doing some automation staff for my `telegram` account using **VBA**. On a `https://web.telegram.org` website I need to fill the textfield with some text and then click.

I tried `.CLick`, `form(0).submit` methods but they do not work both with `class="btn btn-md im_submit im_submit_send"` and `class="im_submit_edit_label nocopy"`.

I understand that the solution is somewhere around `Keyboardevents` and `mouseevents` but I could not find it experimentally.

Please, help me with the code that really works. The `field` and the `"Send" button` images are provided below.

[image]

Comment: .click() always work if you uniquely can identify the element. That is the proper way to go.

Comment: @peakpeak, this example is an exception. I clarified it when wrote about classes I tried on.